# Orbeon: Reset All Form Fields

Tags: orbeon

At the top of the form we have a radio-button that has 3 options. Each option takes the user down a different set of questions. However, it the user changes their mind and say, swaps from option-1 to option-2. Then we want to reset all the form fields except the radio-button.

I have tried syntax such as the following which does clear dropdowns and checkboxes, but it sets a text field to "true":

```
<xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="//SubScn2//*[empty(*)]" value="if (//MainCtrl = '1') then 'true' else ."/>
```

Form example: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/4d48d3f7be57ecaeecb2d5c14ce2a50cf85f7475

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried this suggestion too, but it doesn't work either:

<xforms:setvalue ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" 
    xxforms:iterate="//*[empty(*) and string() = '']" ref="."> </xforms:setvalue>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is good. If you wanna clear all field just use `value="if (//MainCtrl = '1') then '' else ."`. If you want except some fields so make xPath in `xxf:iterate="//SubScn2//*[not(self::SubScn2_C3)]"` more specific.
Some like `"//SubScn2//*[empty(*) and not(self::SubScn2_C3)]"`. If you use good names for fields, that condition could look more generally.